# jQuery - only load content of div when fadeIn() is triggered

Tags: jquery, css, html, load

I'm wondering if it's possible to only load the content of a div when it's shown, to reduce browser load. For example, a div is hidden to begin with, but when a button is pressed, a fadeIn() is triggered. Could I make it so that the content of that div is only loaded after it's faded in?

Here is the code I have now:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page1').click(function() {
        $('.page1').fadeOut(250, function() {
            $('.page2').fadeIn(250)
        });
    });
});
```

I'd like to only load the content of .page2 once it's visible.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Please show your code as it stands, together with your attempts.

Comment: @Lee Taylor - Sorry about that, I've added my code.

Comment: look at `$.ajax` or its derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the load from ajax after the fadeIn

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page1').click(function() {
        $('.page1').fadeOut(250, function() {
            $('.page2').fadeIn(250, function(){
                $(".page2").load("/somepage.htm")
            })
        });
    });
});
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the content isn't from another page, it's simply within the div. I just want the content to not be loaded until that div is visible. Is there any way for me to do this while having the content within the page?

Comment: `.load()` also takes a callback. http://api.jquery.com/load/ . You can always use an `iframe`, setting its source like `$('#iframe').attr('src', 'yourpage.php');`

Comment: im not sure I follow you, what do you mean not be loaded? if you want to insert content from another part of the page after fadein you can `$(".somecontent").appendTo(".page2")` in the fadeIn callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    // Please hide your div inside the content div either in css or js.
    $('#contentDiv').css('display', 'none');

    $('.page1').click(function() {
        $('.page1').fadeOut(250);
        $('.page2').fadeIn(250, function(){
            $('#contentDiv').css('display', 'block');
        })
    });
});
```